# Difference between stored procedures and extended stored procedures

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

What is the basic difference between SQL Server stored procedures (sp_) and extended stored procedures (xp_)? Why there are extended procedures anyway?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Extended stored procedures are written in c/c++(I believe anything that can create a DLL in native code), stored procedures are written in T-SQL

extended stored procedures exist because they allow you to do things that you cannot do in T-SQL like running DOS command (xp_cmdshell)

BTW do not name your procs starting with sp_..that is bad practice...see [Don't start your procedures with SP_](http://blogs.lessthandot.com/index.php/DataMgmt/DBProgramming/MSSQLServer/don-t-start-your-procedures-with-sp_)

Comment: When you say that they are written in C/C++, you mean by the user right?

Answer (score 3):

An extended stored procedure executes code that is not SQL.  It's normally written with external code like in C++.

[Using Extended Stored Procedures](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190987)